# Mass Assignment Error simple_form nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, simple-form, mass-assignment

I really can't figure this one out. I've read a lot of similar problems regarding the mass assignment error but every solution I've tried has failed.

I'm trying to nest my institution model into my course model using accepts_nested_attributes_for & simple_form. My code is as follows:

Course Model:

```
  # Attributes 
  attr_accessible :class_end, :class_start, :cost, :effort, :level, :name, :overview, :prerequisites, :tags, :tag_list

  # Associations 
  belongs_to :institution 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :institution
```

Institution Model:

```
# Attributes
attr_accessible :bio, :city, :country, :name, :state, :twitter_url, :type, :url, :image_url, :email

 # Associations
 has_many :courses
```

View of nested simple_form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@course) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :institutions do |i| %>
    <%= i.input :name %>            
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :overview %>
    <%= f.input :cost %> 
    <%= f.input :level %>
    <%= f.input :tag_list %> 
    <%= f.input :class_start %>
    <%= f.input :class_end %>
    <%= f.input :effort %>
    <%= f.input :prerequisites %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: institutions

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GRoBHYhpv3QyzvH2UHBaJQ/62+9QIDKIwp/VLiLMjus=",
 "course"=>{"institutions"=>{"name"=>"asdfa"},
 "name"=>"sdaf",
 "overview"=>"asdf",
 "cost"=>"Free",
 "level"=>"Beginner",
 "tag_list"=>"asdf",
 "class_start(1i)"=>"2012",
 "class_start(2i)"=>"9",
 "class_start(3i)"=>"18",
 "class_end(1i)"=>"2012",
 "class_end(2i)"=>"9",
 "class_end(3i)"=>"18",
 "effort"=>"asdf",
 "prerequisites"=>"asdf"},
 "commit"=>"Create Course"}
```

Comment: By nesting do you mean you want to create institution at the same time as you creating course? Or do you just want to display a drop down with existing institutions?

Comment: Both. I want to be able to select an existing institution or add one if it doesn't exist. Thanks again for taking the time to help me.

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to do both, not impossible, just difficult. I would change course form to just have a drop down with existing institutions using <%= f.association :institution, :collection => Institution.all %> and use something like cocoon gem on institution form to add classes under institution. Adding institutions under classes is kind of backwards, just my 2c.

Comment: Great thanks. I might just have a link to the Institution form if the Institution doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add institution_attributes to attr_accessible of the Course and use proper name for fields_for, I think it should be :institution, not :institutions. Form should look like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@course) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :institution do |i| %>
    <%= i.input :name %>            
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :overview %>
  <%= f.input :cost %> 
  <%= f.input :level %>
  <%= f.input :tag_list %> 
  <%= f.input :class_start %>
  <%= f.input :class_end %>
  <%= f.input :effort %>
  <%= f.input :prerequisites %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've made the suggested changes but now the form won't render it's just showing 'new course' header.

Comment: You also have an error in your form, it looks like institution has only one field. there should be an end tag after that field. I revised my answer.

Comment: Still no luck. This solution renders everything after the first <% end %> and not the nested attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you 'built' the institution in your controller?

try including:

```
@course.build_institution
```

In your CoursesController